Minimum eigenvalue and semidefinite cone
I have an LMI in the form: $G + x_1F_1 + \cdots + x_nF_n \succeq 0$, where $G$ and $F_i$ are symmetric matrices. Specifically, $G=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$ has only one negative eigenvalue $\lambda_n$ and its corresponding eigenvector $u_n$, and $F_i$ and $G$ do not share the same eigenvectors. If I want to evaluate the "effectiveness" of $F_i$ in moving $G$ toward the positive semidefinite cone $\mathbb{S}^n$, are the following claims correct?
Let $\alpha_i = {\rm tr}(F_i, u_nu_n^T)$ be the projection of $F_i$ on $u_nu_n^T$.
(1) If $\alpha_i > 0$, then $\lambda_{\rm min}(G + F_i) > \lambda_n$, meaning $G + F_i$ is closer to $\mathbb{S}^n$.
(2) If $\alpha_i < 0$, then $\lambda_{\rm min}(G + F_i) < \lambda_n$, meaning $G + F_i$ is leaving $\mathbb{S}^n$.
Thanks in advance.
